# How to add 1 to each letter in a string and print?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to access each character in a string and add 1 to it before printing out the text. Eg. my code will prompt the user for a text ie. hello and it should print that text plus 1 character(i.e. output "ifmmp" when the input is "hello"). From my code below, instead of a for loop, I am trying to use a while loop to do this however I am running into some issues and it doesn't seem to print the response. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
// Libraries
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
    // If
    if (argc == 2 && (atoi(argv[1]) > 0))
     for(int i = 0, len = strlen(argv[1]); i < len; i++)
        {
            char n = argv[1][i];
            int digit = isdigit(n);

            if (!digit)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }

            else
            {
              string plain = get_string("plaintext: ");
              int k = 0;
              int len_plain = strlen(plain);
              while (len_plain > k)
                    k++;
                    char cipher = plain[k];


                    {
                         printf("%c\n", cipher);
                    }
            }
        }
    else
    {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: *printf("%c\n", cipher+1);* Out of that I do not understand at all the interrest of the beginning of *main* and your usage of argv[1] and test about it because you do not really use it

Comment: Thanks @bruno for your input. cipher +1 doesn't work i've tried this already.

Comment: because this is not the only problem, all the beginning of main has no sense, what do you want to do with argv[1] ? to get the number of text to read then write with +1 in each char ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be:

> am trying to access each character in a string and add 1 to it before printing out the text

That can be done in many different ways - here is one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[10] = "hello";
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i])
    {
        ++str[i];  // Add 1
        ++i;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ifmmp
```